# Kaldi librispeech data preparation error

Tags: bash, perl, kaldi

I'm trying to do ASR system. Im using kaldi manual and librispeech corpus.
In data preparation step i get this error

```
utils/data/get_utt2dur.sh: segments file does not exist so getting durations 
from wave files 
utils/data/get_utt2dur.sh: could not get utterance lengths from sphere-file 
headers, using wav-to-duration
utils/data/get_utt2dur.sh: line 99: wav-to-duration: command not found
```

And here the piece of code where this error occures

```
if cat $data/wav.scp | perl -e '
    while (<>) { s/\|\s*$/ |/;  # make sure final | is preceded by space.

        @A = split;
        if (!($#A == 5 && $A[1] =~ m/sph2pipe$/ &&
                          $A[2] eq "-f" && $A[3] eq "wav" && $A[5] eq "|")) { exit (1); }

        $utt = $A[0]; $sphere_file = $A[4];
        if (!open(F, "<$sphere_file")) { die "Error opening sphere file $sphere_file"; }
            $sample_rate = -1;  $sample_count = -1;
            for ($n = 0; $n <= 30; $n++) {
                $line = <F>;
                if ($line =~ m/sample_rate -i (\d+)/) { $sample_rate = $1; }
                if ($line =~ m/sample_count -i (\d+)/) { $sample_count = $1; 
            }
            if ($line =~ m/end_head/) { break; }
         }
         close(F);
         if ($sample_rate == -1 || $sample_count == -1) {
             die "could not parse sphere header from $sphere_file";
         }
         $duration = $sample_count * 1.0 / $sample_rate;
         print "$utt $duration\n";
} ' > $data/utt2dur; then
echo "$0: successfully obtained utterance lengths from sphere-file headers"
    else
        echo "$0: could not get utterance lengths from sphere-file headers, 
using wav-to-duration"
    if command -v wav-to-duration >/dev/null; then
        echo  "$0: wav-to-duration is not on your path"
        exit 1;
    fi
```

In file wav.scp i got such lines:

```
6295-64301-0002 flac -c -d -s /home/tinin/kaldi/egs/librispeech/s5/LibriSpeech/dev-clean/6295/64301/6295-64301-0002.flac |
```

In this dataset i have only flac files(they downloaded via provided script) and i dont understand why we search **wav-files**? And how run data preparation correctly(i didnt change source code in this manual.

Also, if you explain to me what is happening in this code, then I will be very grateful to you, because i'm not familiar with bash and perl.

Thank you a lot!

Comment: To have perl do things, it needs to have the `$data/wav.scp` file present. Currently, it's outputting the else part, and fails as `wav-to-duration` is not found.

Answer (score 1):

The problem I see from this line

```
utils/data/get_utt2dur.sh: line 99: wav-to-duration: command not found
```

is that you have not added the kaldi tools in your path.
Check the file path.sh and see if the directories that it adds to your path are correct (because it has ../../.. inside and it might not match your current folder setup)

As for the perl script, it counts the samples of the sound file and then it divides with the sample rate in order to get the duration. Don't worry about the 'wav' word, your files might be on another format, it's just the name of the kaldi functions.